# How much should I trust Wiktionary?

Tags: dictionaries

My first reference that I use for English words is Wiktionary. I primarily do so because it's a not-for-profit project, so I don't have to worry about it suddenly charging for subscriptions, or that it will have advertising that links to malware.

But recently, I received some [comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1277/why-should-the-t-in-t-shirt-be-capitalized#comment1997_1277) saying that I shouldn't trust Wiktionary when it says some spellings are superior to other spellings:

> I've argued with Wiktionay for years that it has no business declaring
>   one spelling to be the alternative to another. They should use a
>   heading that doesn't lend superiority to one form such as
>   **Spellings** or **Other spellings**. Wiktionary entries vary as to how one word is given the "main" entry and others the "alternatives".
>   Sometimes there's a Google Fight, sometimes it's first come first
>   served, sometimes there's a small battle between who is right among
>   British English and American English! **Do not trust these Wiktionary
>   labels!**

and

> Another piece of advice: Don't expect any dictionary to be
>   prescriptive unless it's older than Webster's Third New World
>   Dictionary. By this time all major English dictionaries published in
>   Britain and USA had firmly chosen the path of descriptivism. That
>   means they claim to describe how the language is used, and
>   specifically do not tell people the correct way to use the language.
>   For questions of usage you would do better to consult style guides,
>   such as *Strunk and White*.

So now I'm wondering how much I should trust Wiktionary.

Currently, my thoughts are:

1. Wiktionary is a single source of information. As with any information source, if you really want to be sure, you'd want to check multiple, independent, sources.
2. Wiktionary theoretically has the same vulnerabilities as Wikipedia. These include people engaging in [internet vandalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandalism_on_Wikipedia), people editing a wiki to push an agenda, people who are editing Wiktionary in good faith but who are biased, and lack of editorial oversight. However, as Wiktionary isn't as high-profile as Wikipedia, and Wiktionary is slightly more difficult to edit than Wikipedia, I don't think these are major problems.
3. Wiktionary sometimes incorporates information from out-dated public domain sources.
4. Wiktionary provides information that a dictionary shouldn't be providing.

With regards to point 4, what information does Wiktionary provide that a dictionary shouldn't provide? Is it merely being prescriptivist in the spelling of a word, or are there other ways it's providing information it shouldn't? For example, should I use Wiktionary to decide whether talking about "a Japanese" rather than "a Japanese person" is [offensive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183/why-is-a-japanese-offensive)?

Comment: Your ##1-3 are dandy. #4, is the information accurate? #1 is the only important one. As for @hippietrail's remarks: how much should you trust a source which refers you to Strunk & White?

Comment: Although I'm willing to trust **most** of the science articles on Wikipedia, I prefer other sources: so many of the Wikipedia science articles are poorly written even if accurate. I'd trust Wiktionary as far as I trust The Urban Dictionary, which is about as far as I can toss a telephone pole given that my left shoulder has been fractured for the last two weeks. "Nonprofit" and "egalitarian" are feelgood labels that mean nothing when they're not outright lies, as they often are. Now that everyone's an "authority", there are no authorities. Trust no one: "Everybody lies", G. House, TVMD.

Comment: I really like #1. When it comes to dictionaries, two or three usually work much better than one. OneLook and Wordnik are two particularly good sources because they glean from multiple dictionaries. [OneLook results](http://www.onelook.com/?w=Japanese) usually include a link to Wiktionary.

Comment: I can't understand how can this question be `on-topic`? This should be migrated to meta! Whether wikitionary/OED/OALD/Grammar girl is correct or not should not be our topic of concern here. It should be migrated to meta, so that community can decide whether they will abide by them or not. But it is not really constructive here. This question can only give rise to speculations.

Comment: Actually I think whether a question such as this belongs on ell or on meta.ell is a question that should be asked (on meta.ell). I tend to agree with @Mistu4u that it belongs on meta though.

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265/is-this-question-on-topic)

Comment: How is this a Meta question at all? This question is not about our website, but about something outside our website, namely Wiktionary. Therefore it cannot be a Meta question, I would say? Besides, I think the question is fine: it has already receives several very interesting answers, and it is surely something language learners will find informative.

Comment: @Cerberus, Meta is a place where we discuss about a question's relevance in the main site. As for your second thought, questions which are although not good for a site but surprisingly has received enough upvotes/answers are locked if necessary due to "historical reasons".

Comment: Don't worry too much about #2, it usually takes less than 2 hours for any form of vandalism to be crushed. Subtle mistakes are probably harder to spot though. As for #3, nothing is truly up to date, you'd need a computer set up to parse every single submission to the internet as it's uploaded to be truly up to date.

Comment: The comment 'That means they claim to describe how the language is used, and specifically do not tell people the correct way to use the language. ' is extremely contentious. If there were even agreement among prescriptivists on 'what is correct',  and 'which year one should look back to for the correct version (of grammar, meaning, spelling ...)', they might have half a leg to stand on. / Style guides can certainly not be claimed to be totally prescriptive, and disagree on recommendations.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

---warning: this is now a partially obsolete answer. The Oxforddictionaries.com site doesn't exist anymore, redirecting to a different site and I'm no longer up to date with what is and what isn't a good dictionary --

---

From my personal experience, [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/) has became *my* "first reference" - Wiktionary may have most words, but their entry quality often varies a lot, and many have very limited range of listed meanings. Meanwhile, Oxford Dictionaries seems to go for depth instead of breadth; each entry delves into a large number of meanings - I had quite a few questions on EL&U closed as "General Reference" because I'd check Wiktionary, Merriam-Webster and such, while only oxforddictionaries.com contained an entry for the meaning I was looking for.<sup>1)</sup>

Still, first Oxford Dictionaries is updated *slower* than Wiktionary; it may be "behind the times" concerning some entries. So, if you have doubts about Oxford Dictionaries entry, feel free to:

- Check Wiktionary
- Check Wiktionary's "History" page for given entry and find when the given meaning was added. If it was added recently, you may trust it's too new for Oxford Dictionaries.
- Check [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com). It's completely unreliable but the bleeding edge of slang that doesn't make its way into more "respectable" dictionaries for years yet.

In essence, going from most reliable and thorough and narrow to most unreliable, shallow and broad; Wiktionary is a step in the middle of that route and a good choice if it's to be your one-stop resource, but not the best if you actually want to *research* given word.

<sup>1) example: Wiktionary, along with a bunch of others I checked did not have the meaning of *grunt* as *mechanical power, especially in a motor vehicle*.</sup>

Comment: @snailplane: oxforddictionaries.com use somewhat abridged and harder to navigate but still mostly complete entries from OED - for free. The official [OED](http://www.oed.com/) is a paid resource.

Comment: Well then, 'duh, I've been misguided! Nevertheless, oxforddictionaries.com tends to have better quality entries than competitors - even if not as many of these entries.

Comment: I assume a response challenging 'oxforddictionaries.com use somewhat abridged and harder to navigate but still mostly complete entries from OED' has been deleted. Lexico and OED are completely different dictionaries. You should revise your answer here as it's confusing and misleading. // OED certainly goes deepest and is most stringently edited, but there are two other quality English dictionaries (ignoring Wiktionary) containing more headwords.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oxforddictionaries.com has gone down the crapper, changed their source and is now exceptionally shallow.  I wish I knew a better alternative, of their former depth. But as it stands now, this answer is obsolete and I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: As far as I know, the dictionary (not the OED) you referred to merely changed its name to Lexico. There will doubtless have been some new additions, adjustments, reformatting, but Lexico remains a fine dictionary. But I've never had a major problem, as far as I can remember, with Wiktionary. Lacking in depth on occasion, certainly ... but I've never thought they'd included entries for strings that hadn't got reasonable currency.  Sometimes, admittedly, I've had to search outside all the standard dictionaries, and on 'LanguageLog' say, for an unusual sense that I want to find support for.

Comment: The definitions by [**Lexico**](https://www.lexico.com/) are the same as formerly used by "Oxford Dictionaries”, in fact on its website it says the site is "powered" by Oxford. I'd be careful before lambasting a dictionary website and saying their content is crap  `Oxford Dictionaries has gone down the crapper` without citing facts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ah so yet another change... Last I checked it, it went from the most comprehensive I knew, to the shallowest. Now that site is gone, replaced by something else. At this point I'm clueless, so I think I should just delete this answer.

Comment: Are you're absolutely sure you're not confusing the ex-Oxford Dictionaries (online) with The Oxford English Dictionary? When I first joined EL&U I had no idea that Oxford had different dictionaries.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not sure of *anything* at this point. What I know is when I first posted this answer I believed oxforddictionaries.com was the online presence of OED and referred to it that way. Which apparently - possibly - I-think-but-I-can-be-wrong wasn't the case. Regardless, oxforddictionaries.com was the resource I was using and intended to reference at that time, and which at one point massively deteriorated in quality and I ceased visiting it.

Comment: The former was the free but much shorter version of the latter, which is viewable only to libraries and yearly subscribers meanwhile the paper version (discontinued) cost a small fortune and if my memory serves well, it consisted of twelve or thirteen volumes.

Answer (score 20):

Being an administrator on Wiktionary, my answer may be slightly biased.

1) Wiktionary is a multilingual dictionary and each Wiktionary site attempts to translate words from all known languages into one single language (e.g., en.wikt for all languages into English). This is one advantage over OED or Webster.

2) Wiktionary (or volunteers who work on the website) strives to be descriptive. However, because we are all biased in one way or another, sometimes prescriptive information gets included in the dictionary. Unfortunately, because it is editable by every man and their dog on the Internet, sometimes these flaws get overlooked.

3) One may consider Wiktionary as a bridge between Urban Dictionary and more authoritative dictionaries like Oxford. As long as a term passes the [CFI](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aCFI), it may be included provided references are given for the term. This is often at the discretion of administrators such as myself and if a term is disputed, it gets put on [RFD](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aRFD) or [RFV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aRFV) to be checked and dealt with accordingly. There are also issues such as the offensiveness of certain terms, which are often dealt with on [Tea room](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aTR). This IS one of the best things about Wiktionary. Everything is open for discussion.

I believe that in order to understand how Wiktionary works, one needs to tread its waters by contributing to it and engaging oneself in active discussions.

Just a note to the other contributors to ELL, if you find a term is missing an entry or a definition. You are welcome to add it, instead of complaining about it being absent. Wiktionary is a wiki and I am sure by now, most people would be familiar with the concept. This is how I started. I made mistakes along the way, but be sensible and be ready to learn and you will go a long way.

There are some extremely talented people on the website, some fluent in a dozen languages. Maybe you will be one of them too.

Comment: Slightly biased it may be, but then again arguably you're more than justified in pushing back against what I perceive as a certain bias *against* Wiktionary here on ELU. In the end, I suspect the problem is that OP is essentially looking for an authoritative *prescriptivist* reference, but dictionaries (and linguists) have largely abandoned that role. I think Wiktionary does a pretty good job, and I commend you for your part in it.

Comment: Also, if you find that a term is missing from Wiktionary but don't feel capable of writing an entry yourself, you can also [request that it be added](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Requested_entries_(English))

Comment: "One may consider Wiktionary as a bridge between Urban Dictionary and more authoritative dictionaries like Oxford." It's not in the middle, it's vastly closer to Oxford. Urban dictionary definitions are jokes puns and dirty humor, it doesn't have parts of speech, conjugations, pronunciations, etymologies... Urban dictionary only common feature with wiktionary is that both might include some slang and common parlance, but the approaches couldn't be further from each other.

Comment: @Santropedro A 'bridge' doesn't mean a middle ground - it's fascinating how you interpreted as such.  I certainly agree with you on the fact that it's closer to the Oxford end of the bridge than Urban. However not everyone would agree with you, hence my 'middle ground' answer with its reference to a bridge - which part of bridge one is on is up to one's opinion and experience.

Comment: There is not a single 'Oxford'. And the different works are certainly not situated together at the end of a perceived continuum (though OED is probably at one end). Discussing the merits of dictionaries when one is not even aware of the actual works hardly inspires confidence in any judgements put forward.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth He never even implied there was a single Oxford dictionary, Edwin, so I guess that makes your entire point irrelevant. Oxford is a name, and it's synonymous with quality dictionaries. You even agreed OED would be at one end, which should have been enough to see the point. It doesn't matter how many there are.

Comment: @Rokit If 'Oxford' is here intended to be short for 'the dictionaries produced by Oxford, at the very least 'One may consider Wiktionary as a bridge between Urban Dictionary and more authoritative dictionaries like Oxford' is infelicitous, violating a Gricean maxim or two. There is certainly a strong suggestion that 'Oxford' here refers to a specific work, in parallel with ' Wiktionary' and 'Urban Dictionary'. / Whatever ODO is now called, it is better than OED in some respects (better reflecting current usage). But OED has far more rigorous editing policies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Whether OED or ODO doesn't matter because the outcome would be the same. Their content should be considered more authoritative than Wiktionary. Next time you feel like being snooty to someone, ask yourself what Grice would do.

Comment: @Rokit Grice would write with precision.

Answer (score 13):

- When I want to know what modern people use, I do Google searches, including News searches and Books searches.
- When I want to know what people who like to edit dictionaries as a hobby think, I use Wiktionary.
- When I want to know what a respected British dictionary has to say, I consult my OED Microprint.
- When I want to know what a respected American dictionary has to say, I consult my Webster's 3rd.
- When I want to know what a respected Australian dictionary has to say, I consult my Macquarie's.
- When I want to know what self-styled experts think, I go to the library and look in style guides like Strunk & White (I don't want to actually own one).
- **When I want to learn all I can about a word or phrase**, I use all of these resources and have been known to visit multiple libraries and bookshops to find as many different dictionaries and other references as possible.

I *trust* some of these sources and take some *with a grain of salt*, but I don't take any single one as an absolute and incontestable authority.

---

- When I want to give back to the community I edit [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org) and participate on [`english.stackexchange.com`](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [`ell.stackexchange.com`](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi hippietrail :). Well said.

Answer (score 7):

**Trust No One** <sup>(1)</sup>. It's the only scientific approach.

- There's no silver bullet. Dictionaries are written by people. People make mistakes;
- As a language learner, it is well possible that **you** simply misunderstand the meaning they wanted to convey;
- [Languages evolve](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/951/27). What was correct yesterday is not necessarily correct today. Remember, five years ago it was grammatical to write *e-mail*. Today, *email* is preferred. It is well possible that a single source is not updated;
- Using various sources not only helps learning different opinions. It also makes you familiar with different methods of explanation, a good asset by itself.

As per #4, the answer is the same. Some sources may not simply contain sufficient information about whether or not a certain word is offensive in every geographic area or logical context.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> As a nice exception, you may always trust me. :)

Comment: *Email* is really only preferred because people are too lazy to press the - key on a keyboard. (I regret to say that I am one of them)

Answer (score 1):

Like Wikipedia, the problem with Wiktionary is its sheer importance; it's the largest single repository. It is not well structured. Like every dictionary, it is demonstrably biased. It is extensively cited by linguistic researchers; this practice is discouraged by the community as it does not claim or attempt to be authoritative. YMMV, you're just going to have to make a decision whether it fits your goals and specs.

Comment: Yep, I have to use whatever dictionary the publisher's style manual tells me to use: Merriam-Webster's 11th New Collegiate, Oxford British English, Dorland's Medical, or Steadman's Medical. Otherwise, I make my own decisions and the publishers don't care.